# Once clicking the select button of a row, a gridview appears between that row and the rest of the gridview. Possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'd like to have the user click the select button of, lets say, the 250th row of a 400 row gridview. When they click that, then another gridview that's 3x12 appears below that row, then the 150 other rows appear below that. Is this at all possible? I guess I could create a whole other div that'll have three gridviews that output depending on being <= and > the index of the selected row.

**It starts as:**

Gridview rows 1-400

**Then after row 350 is selected is it:**

Gridview rows 1-350

---

Gridview of row 350 info

---

Gridview rows 351-400.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely  possible, but I would use a `ListView` or `DataList` as your parent container instead, because with a `GridView`, you'll have to put the child list in a column, which will look ugly. This should put you on the right path:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lstOuterList" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID, OtherColumn">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table width="100%">
            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceHolder" />
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text="Expand" OnCommand="LinkButton1_Command" CommandArgument='<%#Container.DisplayItemIndex%>'></asp:LinkButton></td>
            <td><%#Eval("Value")%></td>
            <td><%#Eval("OtherValue")%></td>
            <td><%#Eval("OtherOtherValue")%></td>
        </tr>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="plcInnerList" runat="server">
            <asp:ListView ID="lstInnerList" runat="server" Width="100%">
                <LayoutTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4">                                
                            <div style="padding:20px;background-color:#fffeee;">
                                <table width="100%">
                                    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceHolder" />
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </td>                        
                    </tr>
                </LayoutTemplate>   
                <ItemTemplate> 
                    <tr>                       
                        <td><%#Eval("Value")%></td>
                        <td><%#Eval("OtherValue")%></td>
                        <td><%#Eval("OtherOtherValue")%></td>  
                    </tr>                         
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
        </asp:PlaceHolder>
    </ItemTemplate>        
</asp:ListView>
```

And when the user clicks the LinkButton/Button in DataList1, do something like this:

```
protected void LinkButton1_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    //pass index of item in command argument
    var itemIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);      

    //find the pnlChildView control
    var innerPlaceHolder = lstOuterList.Items[itemIndex].FindControl("plcInnerList") as PlaceHolder;
    if (innerPlaceHolder != null)
    {
        innerPlaceHolder.Visible = !innerPlaceHolder.Visible;          
        if (innerPlaceholder.Visible)
        {
            var innerList = innerPlaceHolder.FindControl("lstInnerList") as ListView;
            if (innerList != null)
            {
                //the id to retrieve data for the inner list
                int keyValue = (int)lstOuterList.DataKeys[itemIndex]["ID"];

                //bind the list using DataList1 data key value
                innerList.DataSource = new DataTable("DataSource"); //your datasource
                innerList.DataBind();
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh I've never used a ListView, I'll have to give this a shot. Thanks!

Comment: Updated my example to use a `ListView` instead of a `DataList`. The `ListView` is much better suited for this type of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

one way is:

on the rowcommand of the main grid:

- create c# code for the grid will be inside  `GridView grd = new GridView();`
- bind this instance like any other grid
- add on the controls from the main grid current line, should be something like

  ```
  e.Cells[0].Controls.Add(grd);
  ```

I don't have VS here right now but I guess you could get the idea, I use this approach all the time

Comment: So this would create a Gridview without any datasource or formatting?

Comment: right after you create "grd" you can bind it like any other grid(bind it before adding to the .Controls.), and access it's properties such "Autogeneratecolumn" and add custom columns...the only difference it will be done on the codebehind... just try it out